# On creating a new user in odoo, as we assign some group to user, how to do some operation?

Tags: odoo-9

Look at the following image, I want to make Client drop down visible as User assigns 'Clients' group to a new user otherwise it should be invisible.
How to do this?

[Click To see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fx13.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should the make the visibilty limited for the menus under dropdown.

example:

```
<menuitem id="menu_id" name="name"
parent="parentmenu_id" sequence="0"
groups="id_of_client_access_group"
/>
```